# Visual Studio 2012 MVC page doesn't update after refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2010 I can change cshtml file with the project running, save it, refresh the page in the browser and see my changes take effect. But, for some reason I can't see my changes when I refresh the page while running a Visual Studio 2012 project. I have to rerun the project to see my changes. Needless to say, it makes developing in VS 2012 impossible, because I can't test my changes out very quickly. So, unless, I can get this to work in VS 2012, I'll have to stick to VS 2010. Can anyone help me with this?

P.S I had installed Visual Studio Update 2 hoping that it would fix this issue, but it didn't get fixed

Comment: In your *.csproj: Is `MvcBuildViews` set to `true`?

Comment: I had tried setting it to true, but it doesn't work either. I can't believe that this such a standard feature in VS 2010 doesn't work in VS 2012 after TWO F*ING updates coming from Microsoft.

Comment: If set to `true`, you have recompile the project. If set to `false`, a refresh should be enough. I don't think its Microsofts fault. I have successfully migrated multiple VS2010 MVC projects to VS2012, without such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Tools->Options->Environment->Documents->

Checked first option with suboption

Detecked when file is changed...
    Auto-load changes..

I hope after ctrl+f5 it works...

or maybe

Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run-> On Run, when projects are out of date 
Choose Always Build

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but neither option that you had provided worked.

Comment: the above don't apply to the scenario mentoned in the question in any way